# Canonical class of blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry

1. Let $B_1 \to X_1=\mathbb P^n$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb P^n$ along a linear subspace $\mathbb P^k$.
2. Let $B_2 \to X_2$ be the blow up of a quadratic cone $X_2=\{x^2=yz\} \subset \mathbb A^3$ in its vertex $p$.

I need to calculate $K_{B_i}$. As any blow up is an isomophism ouside of the exceptional locus, $K_{B_i}=\pi^*K_{X_i}+D_i$, where a divisor $D_i$ has support on the exceptional divisor $E_i$. As in both cases $E_i$ is an irreducible subvariety, $D_i=a_i E_i$ with $a_i \in \mathbb Z$, so it is necessary to find this two numbers.

1. Are $a_i$ a priory positive?
2. Is it true that $a_1=1$ because $X_1=\mathbb P^n$ is smooth?
3. What sense does $K_{X_2}$ have for $X_2$ a quadratic cone? The canonical divisor may be defined outside of the singular locus which is of codimension $>1$, but can I consider it as a section of a vector bundle?
4. What exactly are $a_i$?
5. What is $K_{B_2}$ in terms of $Pic(B_2)$?

Comment: I believe Hartshorne Chapter 2 Ex8.5 contains some answers to your questions.